# How to write to multiple columns in excel file from a text file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('output_sample2.txt', sep="-", header= "lowestMarks")
dataframe1.to_csv('output_sample2.csv', index=None)
```

I am trying the above code to split data from a txt file to an excel file under 3 different columns with column names.

The above code is splitting into only two columns.

*Sample text file*

0-30 fail

30-70 pass

70-100 distinction

*Desired output*

[image: Desired output]

Thank you.

Comment: Of course it's only splitting into two columns, you only have one `-` in the text file.

Comment: check the columns in your dataframe before writing it as csv.

Comment: @BigBen I cannot change the text file format. I have to split it on the space too to get the third column. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv('output_sample2.txt', sep="-", header= "lowestMarks")
dataframe1['Result'] = dataframe1.iloc[1].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x:x[-1])
dataframe1.to_csv('output_sample2.csv', index=None)
```

This will construct 3rd column by splitting the second column by space then take the last item in the splitted list